# how can multiple processes use one common list concurrently in Erlang?

Tags: concurrency, erlang

I understand that `Erlang` is all about concurrency and we use `spawn/spawn_link` to create a process what I don't understand is **how can all processes use one common list of users concurrently?** say an ordict/dict storage.

What I am trying to do is;
1. A Spawned User process Subscribes/Listens to registered process `A`
2. Registered process `A` stores `{Pid, Userid}` of all online users
3. When some user sends a message user's process asks process `A` wether recipient is online or not.

sending a message in `erlang` is asynchronous but is it also asynchronous when a user is being sent messages by multiple users?

Comment: in addition to Steve answer, I provided a "toy" module to illustrate how it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make process `A` a [`gen_server` process](http://erlang.org/doc/man/gen_server.html) and keep any data structure storing online users as the process state. Storing a new user or deleting one could be done with [`gen_server:cast/2`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/gen_server.html#cast-2), and checking to see if a user is online could be done with [`gen_server:call/2`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/gen_server.html#call-2). Alternatively, you could have a `gen_server` create a publicly-readable [`ets table`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html) to allow any process to read it to check for online users, but storing and deleting would still require casts to the `gen_server`. You could even make the table publicly readable and writable so that any process could store, delete, or check users. But keep in mind that an `ets` table is by default destroyed when the process that creates it dies, so if you need it to stay around even if the `gen_server` that created it dies, you must arrange for it to be inherited by some other process, or [give it to a supervisor](https://books.google.com/books?id=uXosDAAAQBAJ&pg=PT291&dq=keeping+ets+tables+alive&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwip24DarI3OAhVJx2MKHXwcDpgQ6AEIHjAA#v=onepage&q=keeping%20ets%20tables%20alive&f=false).

Answer (score 1):

A serious solution  should use the OTP behaviors (gen_server, supervisor...) as suggested by Steve.
Anyway I wrote a small example module that implement both a server and clients and that can be started on one node using the command `erl -sname test` for example (or several nodes using `erl -sname node1`, `erl -sname node2`...) .

it includes also an example of a shell session that illustrates most of the cases, I hope it can help you to follow the exchanges, synchronous or asynchronous between processes.

**NOTE :** *the access to the user list is not concurrent, it is not possible if the list is owned by a server process like it is in this example. It is why Steve propose to use an ETS to store the information and do real concurrent accesses. I have tried to write the example with interfaces that should allow a quick refactoring with ETS instead of tuple list.*

```
-module(example).

-export([server/0,server_stop/1,server_register_name/2,server_get_address/2, server_quit/2, % server process and its interfaces
         client/1,quit/1,register_name/2,get_address/2,send_message/3,print_messages/1, % client process and its interfaces
         trace/0]). % to call the tracer for a nice message view

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Client interface
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

client(Node) ->
    % connect the current node to the servernode given in parameter
    % it will fail if the connection cannot be established
    true = net_kernel:connect_node(Node),
    % spawn a client process
    spawn(fun () -> client([],unregistered,{server,Node}) end).

register_name(ClientPid,Name) ->
    % use a helper to facilitate the trace of everything
    send_trace(ClientPid,{register_name,self(),Name}),
    % wait for an answer, it is then a synchronous call
    receive
        % no work needed, simply return any value
        M -> M 
    after 1000 ->
        % this introduce a timeout, if no answer is received after 1 second, consider it has failed
        no_answer_from_client
    end.

get_address(ClientPid,UserName) ->
    send_trace(ClientPid,{get_address,self(),UserName}),
    % wait for an answer, it is then a synchronous call
    receive
        % in this case, if the answer is tagged with ok, extract the Value (will be a Pid)
        {ok,Value} -> Value;
        M -> M 
    after 1000 ->
        no_answer_from_client
    end.

send_message(ClientPid,To,Message) ->
    % simply send the message, it is asynchronous
    send_trace(ClientPid,{send_message,To,Message}).

print_messages(ClientPid) ->
    send_trace(ClientPid,print_messages).

quit(ClientPid) ->
    send_trace(ClientPid,quit).



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% client local functions
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

client(Messages,Name,Server) ->
    receive
        {register_name,From,UserName} when Name == unregistered ->
            % if not yet registered send the request to the server and
            % backward the answer to the requester
            Answer = server_register_name(Server,UserName),
            send_trace(From,Answer),
            NName = case Answer of
                registered -> UserName;
                _ -> Name
            end,
            client(Messages,NName,Server);
        {register_name,From,_} ->
            % if already registered reject the request
            send_trace(From,{already_registered_as,Name}),
            client(Messages,Name,Server);
        {get_address,From,UserName} when Name =/= unregistered ->
            Answer = server_get_address(Server,UserName),
            send_trace(From,Answer),
            client(Messages,Name,Server);           
        {send_message,To,Message} ->
            % directly send the message to the user, the server is not concerned
            send_trace(To,{new_message,{erlang:date(),erlang:time(),Name,Message}}),
            client(Messages,Name,Server);
        print_messages ->
            % print all mesages and empty the queue
            do_print_messages(Messages),
            client([],Name,Server);
        quit ->
            server_quit(Server,Name);
        {new_message,M} ->
            % append the new message
            client([M|Messages],Name,Server);
        _ ->
            client(Messages,Name,Server)
        end.

do_print_messages(Messages) ->
    lists:foreach(fun({D,T,W,M}) -> io:format("from ~p, at ~p on ~p, received ~p~n",[W,T,D,M]) end,Messages).

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Server interface
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

server() ->
    true = register(server,spawn(fun () -> server([]) end)),
    node().

server_stop(Server) ->
    send_trace(Server,stop).

server_register_name(Server,User) ->
    send_trace(Server,{register_name,self(),User}),
    receive
        M -> M
    after 900 ->
        no_answer_from_server
    end.

server_get_address(Server,User) ->
    send_trace(Server,{get_address,self(),User}),
    receive
        M -> M
    after 900 ->
        no_answer_from_server
    end.

server_quit(Server,Name) ->
    send_trace(Server,{quit,Name}).

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% server local functions
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

server(Users) ->
    receive
        stop ->
            ok;
        {register_name,From,User} ->
            case lists:keyfind(User,1,Users) of
                false ->
                    send_trace(From,registered),
                    server([{User,From}|Users]);
                _ -> 
                    send_trace(From,{already_exist,User}),
                    server(Users)
                end;
        {get_address,From,User} ->
            case lists:keyfind(User,1,Users) of
                false ->
                    send_trace(From,{does_not_exist,User}),
                    server(Users);
                {User,Pid} ->
                    send_trace(From,{ok,Pid}),
                    server(Users)
                end;
        {quit,Name} ->
            server(lists:keydelete(Name,1,Users))
    end.



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% global
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

trace() -> 
% start a collector, a viewer and trace the "trace_me" ...
    et_viewer:start([{trace_global, true}, {trace_pattern, {et,max}},{max_actors,20}]).

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% helpers
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

send_trace(To,Message) ->
    % all messages will be traced by "et"
    et:trace_me(50,self(),To,Message,[]),
    To ! Message.

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% shell commands
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% c(example).
% example:trace().
% N = node().
% C1 = example:client(N).
% example:register_name(pid(0,5555,0),"fails").
% example:register_name(C1,"fails_again").
% example:server().
% example:register_name(C1,"Joe").
% C2 = example:client(N).
% example:register_name(C2,"Bob").
% example:print_messages(C1).
% C2 = example:get_address(C1,"Bob").
% example:send_message(C1,C2,"Hi Bob!").
% example:send_message(C1,C2,"Hi Bob! are you there?").
% example:print_messages(C2).
% example:send_message(C2,C1,"Hi Joe! Got your message.").
% example:print_messages(C2).
% example:print_messages(C1).
% example:quit(C1).
% example:get_address(C2,"Joe").
% example:server_stop({server,N}).
% example:get_address(C2,"Joe").
% example:get_address(C1,"Bob").
```

here an extract of the event viewer:

[image]

Comment: How to get the "event viewer" picture?

Comment: In the send_trace function I have added a call to `et:trace_me/5`, it does nothing but it is "preconfigured" to be traced using `et_viewer:start([{trace_global, true}, {trace_pattern, {et,max}},{max_actors,20}])` that I call in the trace/0 function. Beware that you need wx_widget working on your platform. By the way if somebody knows how to force the process <0,59,0> and server on the same time line, I would appreciate.